# Returning a filter result in a different page - Django

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I've searched up but nothing seams to do the trick or be on point.

Let's say i have two websites on page A.html I have a filter (djnago_filter) and B.html is empty. If the user submits the search form he is redirected from page A.html to page B.html where the results are displayed with for loop.

How do I to that?

I was thinking about passing the data from query set to another view but there must be better solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to store and display information on the different views(pages):

1. You could use the **[Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/)**:

```
    #views.py

    #set the session key in the view A:
    request.session['info'] = {'key', 'value'}
    
    #get the session key in the view B:
    info = request.session['info']
    del request.session['info']
```

2. You could use **[Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/)** with [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield):

```
    #app/models.py

    #model to store information from page A
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,
            on_delete=models.DELETE,
            related_name="info")
        info = models.JSONField()

    #views.py
    #store data in the view A:
    from app.models import MyModel
    MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, info={'key', 'value'})
    
    #retrieve data in the view B:
    info = MyModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

But actually, all depends on the logic that you intent to achieve. There are actually other methods like using async Ajax, React, WebSockets...

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as an HTML request parameter inside the url, for example, in your pageA template  will be

```
<a href="{% url 'pageB' %}?some_filter={{ some_filter }}">to page B</a>
```

and inside pageb view, you can take the filter from the request object

```
def page_b_view(request):

    some_filter = request.GET.get('some_filter')
```